# Await a asynchronous function return a range object

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

I'd like to use a function to return a range object, but because the function is asynchronous, when my code reaches `currentRangeSelection.select();`, it is still `null`. How do I force the code to await the function `getCurrentRangeSelection` so I can get the object instead `undefined`?

---

**EDIT 1 - Rick Kirkham**: I've simplified the code so now it is possible just to paste it in the default *Basic API Call (JavaScript)* template in ScriptLab to test it.

After studying Promises for hours, I think I'm close to what I want, but it still doesn't work:

```
$("#run").click(run);

function run() {
    var currentRangeSelection;

    return Excel.run(function (context) {
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                return getCurrentRangeSelection(currentRangeSelection)
            })
            .then(function () {
                // this returns an error because currentRangeSelection is undefined:
                console.log("Outside the function: " + currentRangeSelection.address);
                currentRangeSelection.select();
                return context.sync();
            })
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

function getCurrentRangeSelection(rangeSelection) {
    return Excel.run(function (context) {
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                rangeSelection = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
                rangeSelection.load();
                return context.sync();
            })
            .then(function () {
                // this works:
                console.log("Inside the function: " + rangeSelection.address);
                return context.sync();
            });
    });
}
```

As you can see, now the function returns a `Promise` because it is (I think) the return value of `Excel.run` function, and now I pass the desired return range as a parameter, but still doesn't work.
Any more tips?

---

**EDIT 2 - Rick Kirkham**

(1) I tried to create a function that returns a Promise, so I could insert it in the caller `then` chain. Because of that, my only choice was to pass as reference the parameter that returns the range.

(2) Yes, I agree with you. I think (1) explained why I didn't return a range object in the first place.

(3) Yes, I fixed that.

(4) The original function was more complex and a single method from Office-JS API wouldn't return what I really wanted. I solved my problem by doing this:

```
$("#run").click(run);

function run() {
    var testRange;

    return Excel.run(function (context) {
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                testRange = getCurrentRangeSelection(context);
                testRange.load();
                return context.sync();
            })
            .then(function () {
                console.log(testRange.address); // this works
                return context.sync();
            });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}


function getCurrentRangeSelection(context) {
    var rangeSelection = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    var activeWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var usedRange = activeWorksheet.getUsedRange();
    return usedRange.getIntersection(rangeSelection);
}
```

My next question you answered with your edit: "What if I wanted the function `getCurrentRangeSelection` to return an already `loaded` object?"

Thanks for the example and the answers!

Comment: FYI that part of the issue with the first code was that you were effectively doing two different `Excel.run`-s.  Things can get really confusing when you do.  I recently added a long section about it in [my book](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins), "Using objects outside the “linear” Excel.run or Word.run flow (e.g., in a button-click callback, in a setInterval, etc.)".  However, this case doesn't really apply to you, as you *are* trying to have a linear flow -- and if it's a linear flow, then a single `Excel.run` should suffice.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure if you still have a question or if everything has already been answered by Ricky -- but if you still do, just ask it on a separate StackOverflow thread.

Comment: Everything is answered, thanks for the comment and yes, I read your book regarding this part and finally grasped the concept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Redesign the `getCurrentRangeSelection` function to return a Promise object. Then call the `then` method of the promise object to call `currentRangeSelection.select()`

**Edit in light of the OP's comments below and rewritten question:**

Please go to [this sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-MarkdownConversion/blob/master/Word-Add-in-JavaScript-MDConversionWeb/Home.js) and see the `getDocumentFilePath` function in the home.js file. Structure your `getCurrentRangeSelection` method like it and pass the context object to it as a parameter. Then use the context object to get the currently selected range with the `context.workbook.getSelectedRange()` method. Then pass the thing you want to return (the currently selected range, I presume) as the parameter to the `resolve` method.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to do that. Any references?

Comment: Just Bing "JavaScript Promises" and you'll get lots of hits including beginner's guides and tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it still doesn't work. Could you see the edited considerations?

Comment: SEE MY REVISED ANSWER: Also, some puzzles about your latest code: (1) Why are you intentionally passing an undefined object to a method? (2) A function named "getWhatever" should return a "whatever" object. Your getCurrentRangeSelection doesn't return the currently selected range. It just assigns it to a variable and does nothing with that variable. (3) You are calling an Excel.run inside another Excel.run. I don't think that's a good practice. (4) What do you want your getCurrentRangeSelection to do that isn't done by context.workbook.getSelectedRange();?

Comment: I edited it again. Thanks for the answers and the link!